# Add authorized key with only one SSH login

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

The typical procedure for a user to add an authorized key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is:

1. Copy the public key on the remote host with `scp`.
2. Connect with `ssh` and add the key to the file.

Such a procedure is for instance described in an answer to ”[How to add a ssh key to remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17400719/3990969)”

Is this possible to add the key in only one step — with only one login to the remote server? An answer working on FreeBSD and Debian GNU/Linux (both with OpenSSH) would be great.

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh-copy-id user@hostname.com -i filename_of_key_to_copy
```