# How to password less SSH to Host from Container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes-pod, openssh

[Actual requirement: I need to launch a bash shell on the host from a kubernetes container.]

Is there a way to password-less **SSH** to the Host from a kubernetes container when it has access to host files (any required files/path can be mounted) such as **.ssh**?.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add authorized key with only one SSH login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900499/add-authorized-key-with-only-one-ssh-login)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The answer is the same as it is without involving containers or kubernetes: ensure you have a proper private key available in your container, and the matching public key in the `authorized_keys` file on your host.

Comment: @larsks It is like I have to do SSH from Machin A to B, where A has access to all the B's files because they are mounted to some path in A (so A can use B's files as its own). Now with access to B's ssh related files, can I make SSH from A to B with out password

Comment: @Punisher, I think I can use the answer for my requirement, all I need to do is to copy the containers public key on to the host, I will try copy as I have access to host's file system

Comment: Hi, On container used `ssh-keygen` to create keys, copied the contents of `id_rsa.pub` into host's `.ssh/authorized_keys`. But it is not working, asking for password again. Am I missing something? (anything to do with `known_hosts`, not doing anything here).